# Why sometime I can't delete or add circle on google maps flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps-flutter

I use the `google_maps_flutter` package to display circles around markers, but I encounter an issue where sometimes when I add or remove a circle, it appears to be added or removed from my `Set<Circle>`, but the circle does not actually appear or disappear on the map.

How can I make it so that when I add or remove a circle to/from a `Set<Circle>`, it will display or remove that circle on the map?

Comment: Show us your code ... looks like you don't refresh the ui?